# Glassfish context-root issue

Tags: java, jsf-2, glassfish-3

I'm trying to deploy a JSF-2 application in the root of my glassfish server so that `http://localhost:8080/` leads to my welcome page. For some reason when trying to configure this,  `http://localhost:8080/` leads to glassfish default welcome page while `http://localhost:8080//` leads to mine. If I go to `http://localhost:8080/<welcome-page>` it works, so the context-root seems to work in most cases, it's just the welcome page that has the wrong mapping somehow.

How to fix this?

sun-web.xml:

```
<sun-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/</context-root>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</sun-web-app>
```

web.xml (minus security constraints and other unrelated stuff)

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AlreadyLoggedInRedirectFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/login.jsf</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>AlreadyLoggedInRedirectFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.xdin.competence.jsf.util.AlreadyLoggedInRedirectFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/viewExpired.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.jsf</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

As a side note, the application is *not* the default application of the server, I just want it to be deployed in the root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a special 'feature' from glassfish. Please check out the answers in [How do you deploy a WAR that's inside an EAR as the root (/) context in Glassfish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127492/how-do-you-deploy-a-war-thats-inside-an-ear-as-the-root-context-in-glassfish)

Btw: Which version of glassfish are you using? Is it possible for you to change your application to be the default application?

Comment: Using GF 3.01. In the end, it seems that the issue only existed in Firefox, which is pretty weird. I didn't appear in production environment either so the problem pretty much solved itself. That said, your link does have some useful information, so I'll accept it as an answer.