# Configure the path (localhost) of the war application to be the root (Java EE)

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I want to change the path when I run my war-application locally...
Right now, it is running on the default setting...

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject-war/
```

and I want it to be the root, something like:

```
http://myproject-war.local/
```

or

```
http://myproject:8080/
```

How can I do that???

Note: My app is a Java EE 6 Application with Glashfish using Netbeans 7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post helped me out [How do you deploy a WAR that's inside an EAR as the root (/) context in Glassfish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127492/how-do-you-deploy-a-war-thats-inside-an-ear-as-the-root-context-in-glassfis).

- First, I added a Standard Deployment Descriptor (**application.xml**) to the Enterprise Application Project.
- Then, change the path of the context root of your web application: `<context-root>/myproject-war</context-root>` to `<context-root>/</context-root>` or `<context-root />`
- Finally, (optional) remove or rename the Glashfish index page (or redirect it to the welcome page). located in the Glashfish default folder such as `C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot`

Now the page web application will be visible on: `http://localhost:8080/`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are mixing up stuff here - one thing you can and should do is setting the context root of your application. This is done in the server's deployment descriptor - in your case in `glassfish-web.xml`:

```
<context-root>/myproject</context-root>
```

(See [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html)  for more details.)

What you're asking in your example URLs is changing the host name, which is not related to your application or application server, but to your machine and OS settings.

You may put something in the OS hosts file (`/etc/hosts` on Linux, `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` on Windows), but I don't see the point to do this. Your application runs on some host (may it be `localhost`or some external server) and this is how your URL starts.

Comment: About hosts, I believe is only for port 80 but my port is 8080 and I want to keep that way so don't conflict with other applications in port 80. Also, we have to do some extra configuration in the web server / web container, I had done it in .NET app in the IIS (and Visual Studio)

Comment: @Jaider: Port is again something different from both hostname and application root context - it's configured in your web/application server. Per default, your Glassfish serves 8080.

Answer (score -1):

you can put entry in host file. which is located in "C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc".

127.0.0.1       your_project_name