# Deploy restful api on azure successfully but always return 404 error when i meet the url

Tags: java, azure, tomcat, deployment

In my project, i deployed the jersey api on the azure successfully, and i put the ROOT.war file in the /wwwroot/webapps, and the tomcat successfully to extract the file and all the project stuff showed on this directory.But the app always return 404, i dont know why.
Here is my pom.xml file:

```
 <groupId>patientinformationdisplayer</groupId>
<artifactId>pom</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.28</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- App information -->
        <resourceGroup>team19backend</resourceGroup>
        <appName>team19backend</appName>
        <region>UK south</region>

        <!-- Java Runtime Stack for App on Linux-->
        <linuxRuntime>tomcat 8.5-jre8</linuxRuntime>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>HoloBackend.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I dont know what going on with the deployment , and it took me whole day to do this. Please help me to fix this, so many thanks for you.

Comment: So this is deployed to a web app, correct? What port are you trying to connect to, when communicating with your API?

Comment: The port is {myappname}.azurewebsites.net, and always return 404, do you have any idea about this? thank you very much

Comment: @tiefucai How did you deploy your app?

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy the application to local Tomcat, can you access the site using root URL? 
Recommened way to remove the out-of-the-box ROOT/ directory. Please double check whether you have done that.

You may also want to refer to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html, where it states:

The context path of this web application, which is matched against the beginning of each request URI to select the appropriate web application for processing. All of the context paths within a particular Host must be unique. If you specify a context path of an empty string (""), you are defining the default web application for this Host, which will process all requests not assigned to other Contexts.
This attribute must only be used when statically defining a Context in server.xml. In all other circumstances, the path will be inferred from the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase.

Even when statically defining a Context in server.xml, this attribute must not be set unless either the docBase is not located under the Host's appBase or both deployOnStartup and autoDeploy are false. If this rule is not followed, double deployment is likely to result.

And this link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160565/configure-the-path-localhost-of-the-war-application-to-be-the-root-java-ee ) may help you.

Hope it helps.