# Jenkins behind nginx without subdirectory

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I have Jenkins running inside my Glassfish installation, so Jenkins can be reached @

```
http://localhost:8090/jenkins/
```

I managed to setup nginx so Jenkins can be reached from the outside @

```
http://build.example.com/jenkins/
```

This setup works well so far, but I am not really happy with it. What I would really want to achieve is to hit

```
http://build.example.com
```

in the browser to reach Jenkins.

Here is my current nginx config:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    server_name build.example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

I hope this is possible via some url rewrite, but I'm totally clueless how to do it...

Answer (score 1):

Then change:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
```

to

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/jenkins/;
```

Reference: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

Comment: Unfortunately, its seems not to be this easy, since jenkins creates a lot of links in the form
    `http://build.example.com/jenkins/static/...`
Which then result in a 404

Comment: Nginx cannot do anything with all the links that your backend creates. In this case you should fix your backend.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the problem is the Glassfish configuration.

How about setting in `application.xml` the following value:

```
<context-root/>
```

Instead of the default, which is the name of the WAR file, without the `.war` extension.

There seems to be [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127492/how-do-you-deploy-a-war-thats-inside-an-ear-as-the-root-context-in-glassfis) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

From http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

```
location / {
    rewrite    /jenkins/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/jenkins/;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```