# URL redirection within WARs in the EAR file

Tags: javascript, jsp, redirect, war

Have an EAR file which has multiple WARs. Want to redirect using jsp, from war1 to war2 with context root to load its jsp and consequently the scripts of that war. And also be able to redirect as necessary. The URL should not change during this redirection (due to limitations...)  using Websphere as the app server. Please advise - thanks in advance!

Comment: any help here would be appreciated...

Comment: see if it's of any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127492/how-do-you-deploy-a-war-thats-inside-an-ear-as-the-root-context-in-glassfis